# How to decrease range selection from 4 to 2 to create chart VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, select, range

I have two columns of data, one of which contains half negative numbers and half positive numbers. I have created a chart (scatter with straight lines and markers) for the data, using the code below:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim xData As Range
    Dim yData As Range
    Dim x2Data As Range
    Dim y2Data As Range
    Dim serName As Range


    'set the ranges to get the data and y value label

    Set xData = Application.Selection
    Set yData = Application.Selection
    Set x2Data = Application.Selection
    Set y2Data = Application.Selection

    Set serName = Range("AY2")


    'define range
    Set xData = Application.InputBox("xvalues", , xData.Address, Type:=8)
    Set yData = Application.InputBox("yvalues", , yData.Address, Type:=8)
    Set x2Data = Application.InputBox("x2values", , x2Data.Address, Type:=8)
    Set y2Data = Application.InputBox("y2values", , y2Data.Address, Type:=8)


    'get reference to ActiveSheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'create a new ChartObject at position (4100, 195) with width 400 and height 300
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Set chtObj = sht.ChartObjects.Add(4100, 195, 400, 300)

    'get reference to chart object
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart

    'create the new series
    Dim ser As Series
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    ser.Values = yData
    ser.XValues = xData
    ser.Name = positivedcf
    ser.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    'create second series

    Dim ser2 As Series
    Set ser2 = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    ser2.Values = y2Data
    ser2.XValues = x2Data
    ser2.Name = negativedcf
    ser2.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines




End Sub
```

As you can see, I have used 4 selections in order to chart the graph correctly. It involved selecting a section of each column at a time. What I would like to do now is to create the same chart, but instead of using 4 selections, I would like to only use 2 selections. Ideally, these 2 selections would be just selecting both columns in its entirety. I would like to achieve this using arrays too.

Could anyone help me to figure this out? If it will help you, I can attach a picture of the data I have used in order to create the initial graph. Thank you very much in advance.

***EDIT****

So I tried this below, ends up making the graph in 1 selection, which is great. However the original graph showed both the positive and negative parts of the curve in different colours. I essentially created the original graph using 2 series, which both meet at y=0, giving the effect of it all being one curve, when in theory it is 2 different curves. If that makes sense?

So is there a way to do the same thing: essentially create the graph using 2 series that meet at y=0, showing the positive and negative parts of the curve in different colours, with 2 selections (ideally just highlighting both columns of data in full) instead of the original 4 selections I make?

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim xData As Range
    Dim yData As Range
    Dim serName As Range

    Dim TotalData As Range



    'set the ranges to get the data and y value label

    Set xData = Application.Selection
    Set yData = Application.Selection
    Set TotalData = Application.Selection




    'define range


    Set TotalData = Application.InputBox("AY3:AZ62", , TotalData.Address, Type:=8)
    Set yData = TotalData.Resize(ColumnSize:=1)
    Set xData = TotalData.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)



    'get reference to ActiveSheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'create a new ChartObject at position (4100, 195) with width 400 and height 300
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Set chtObj = sht.ChartObjects.Add(4100, 195, 400, 300)

    'get reference to chart object
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart

    'create the new series
    Dim ser As Series
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    ser.Values = yData
    ser.XValues = xData
    ser.Name = positivedcf
    ser.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines








End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one box to select both columns (x and y)

```
Set TotalData = Application.InputBox("Select all data (x and y)", , TotalData.Address, Type:=8)
```

And then split it into 2 separate columns (x and y)

```
Set xData = TotalData.Resize(ColumnSize:=1)
Set yData = TotalData.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
```

Comment: Which part of my code should I delete? And where should I place what you have written? I've tried a couple of ways but comes up with a Run time error

Comment: This should replace your `Set xData` and `Set yData` lines and you probably need a `Dim TotalData As Range` and a `Set TotalData = Application.Selection` too. If you get stuck please append the code you have tried on your original question.

Comment: If you want the same for your `x2Data` then you should do the same as I did for that too like adding a `Total2Data`. Does that answer your question? If not please give a valid example data and a screenshot to understand it better.